# How do I answer the question in red?

Tags: support, moderation

[image]

I do have a response to that question, but how can I give my answer?

Comment: Is the answer "yes"?

Comment: @billy yes, however, I read that a healthy thread should have multiple answers to the question with the best answer being voted to the top. I was giving it more time for this to happen. When I ask this meta question, I did not know if the red question was automated or if it was being ask by a mod or something.

Answer (score 2):

The red text is reminding you to accept an answer to your question. If you get an answer that is helpful to you and answers the question you should accept that answer by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Accepting an answer give you +2 reputation and +15 reputation to the answerer.

Comment: Thank you, I do understand what the question is asking and even more or less why it is being ask. Is it simply an automated reminder? If it is not meant to be responded to than maybe it should be a statement and not a question. Like, "Please consider accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question". Perhaps I should be asking what the customs are for when to accept an acceptable answer instead though. I feel like I'm following the SE FAQ by waiting to accept in this particular case.

Comment: Yes, it's automated, and although is phrased as a question, it's not an order. It only appears after a few days.